# How to send a command to running container in Kubernetes?

Tags: containers, kubernetes

I can get the IP address of the exposed container through:

```
kubectl get service hello-node
```

Say that I want to run `ls` on this container and obtain the results. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use `kubectl exec ...`. To run `ls`on a containers run:

```
kubectl exec <pod> ls
```

You'll find the pod-id with:

```
kubectl get pods
```

The full documentation can be found on [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_exec/)

Cheers